# extract object inside other object

Tags: javascript

I have next code:

```
let otherObject = {stat: 1, pos: 3, ..... other parameters};

function someF() {
    return {
      valid: false,
      otherObject,
    };
}
```

this function return next object:

```
{
   valid: false,
   otherObject
}
```

but what I need is to get parameter of otherObject:

```
{
   valid: false,
   stat: 1,
   pos: 3,
   .....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
let otherObject = {stat: 1, pos: 3};

function someF() {
    return {
     ...otherObject,
     valid: false,
    };
}

console.log( someF() );
```

Comment: Best to put the `valid: false` after the spread, so that it will not be replaced by existing values that may exist in the source object.